# USB 3.0 Device not detected in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, usb-3

About my setup:

- Windows 8 64-bit.
- X79-UD3 Motherboard.
- Latest Windows 8 USB 3.0 Drivers from motherboard manufacturer website.
- Latest BIOS revision. (F12p)

All right so device manager detects my USB 3.0 ports, so all is well there.

However when I plug in my external USB 3.0 hard drive, windows doesn't even make a beep; the hard drive is not picked up by device manager at all.

The SAME thing happens with Ubuntu 12.10 BUT adding `PCI=nomsi` (as a workaround) to the Grub command line of the Ubuntu boot option makes Ubuntu 12.10 detect my external hard drive.

I also have a few other doubts, if you guys would be kind enough to answer them that include:

- Should `XHCI hand-off` in the UEFI bios be enabled or disabled for Windows 8?
- The difference between `XHCI hand-off` and `EHCI hand-off` and what are it's effects on USB 3.0 functionality?
- And last but not least how can I get Windows 8 to recognize my external hard drive when Ubuntu 12.10 (after the Grub workaround) works fine?

Comment: Tentative answer: Try setting xHCI mode as Auto. If you have both xHCI and EHCI Hand-off then set both of them. If you have "HS Port Switchable" try enabling them.

Comment: There's no auto, just "enable, disabled". Latest BIOS revision btw. I don't have HS Port Switchable either.

Comment: What happens if you enable both xHCI and EHCI Hand-off ?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. Not even detected in device manager, like I've said.

Comment: As the BIOS offers so few options, it might not be advanced enough for usb-3. Maybe you should look first for a firmware/bios update for your model, or ask the Support of your computer maker whether the motherboard supports usb-3. Apropos : which model is your computer? I also remark that detecting the disk is not enough if it functions only at usb-2 speeds.

Comment: @harrymc I already posted the model of my motherboard. Gigabyte X79-UD3. My computer does support USB 3.0 because it works with Ubuntu 12.10. Plus there's Windows 8 drivers for USB 3.0.

Comment: I understand that you built this computer? In my experience Ubuntu is more permissive than Windows for drivers, but there is no guarantee that it works at usb3 speed. Questions: (1) Which usb3 driver do you have in Windows? (2) When XHCI+EHCI hand-off are both disabled does the external disk work at usb2 speed? (3) When the external disk is connected on a usb2 port do you get the message that it can work faster? (4) What make are the usb3 ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that both xHCI and EHCI Hand-offs should be set to Enabled.
More information may be found in the thread [USB 3.0 on Gigabyte UEFI Motherboards - XHCI Mode Explained](http://legacy.tonymacx86.com/viewtopic.php?f=169&t=66178).

If USB-3 does not work, even though your board expressly supports Windows 8,
this may be because your BIOS or drivers are not fully up to date.

The first step is to update the BIOS which is found at [this link](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4050#bios)
(if this is not your exact board model then search for it).

Second, download and install the latest Gigabyte drivers for your motherboard,
available from the same link.

Exercise very great caution, as an unsuccessful BIOS update can brick your computer.
Ensure first that you have a boot installation CD of your current BIOS
(and of course - backups).

<sub>(On second thought, a boot CD will not help if the BIOS is dead, you will need
a repair-shop to get it installed again.)</sub>

Comment: Does not the fact it works under Ubuntu rule out the BIOS as the cause of issues?

Comment: @deed02392: My theory is that the Windows driver requires more capabilities from the BIOS than does Ubuntu, so it needs a more advanced BIOS.

Comment: There was a BIOS update a few days ago and that seemed to have resolved my issue. I was however not sure about XHCI and EHCI so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- *Should XHCI hand-off in the UEFI bios be enabled or disabled for Windows 8?* Enabled
- *The difference between XHCI hand-off and EHCI hand-off and what are it's effects on USB 3.0 functionality?*   only xHCI affects USB 3.0 ports. Set to Enabled for most modern OSs.

Comment: Can you explain *why* this is the case?